Disabling RPI media output
When I connect to my Raspberry Pi via Bluetooth it detects it like headphones and thinks it has media output. I want to disable this.

Here you can see that it appears in the media output of the phone. I don't want it to appear in the media output of the phone. I tried to change the class but it doesn't work.

This has already been posted on the more appropriate Raspberry Pi stack exchange site: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/147778/disabling-rpi-media-output
